# Mail app is not working on my Mac

Tags: mac, icloud, mail.app

I receive emails but I get account error and cannot send.

Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: on the mail app it shows error and then I begin following steps , and never reach any solution,

Comment: this is what happens when i click on the error:Connections to the server “p17-imap.mail.me.com” on the default ports timed out.

Comment: What is the account set here? https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU4Ba.png (notify me by @ankiiiiiii) Also, go to window menu-> connection doctor and see which part is problematic. Also, see this thread for a lot of tips and tricks. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152652/cant-send-outgoing-messages-in-mac-mail?rq=1

Comment: Can also try re-adding the account in system pref -> internet accounts.

Comment: I saw the answer you posted but my problem is with my icloud email, not gemail, would the answer be the same?

Comment: @AlejandraSeeber as Mike said in the comment below, see the vendor(iCloud) settings here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202304

Answer (score 0):

The mail connection doctor window is the best way to diagnose any mail send failure, setup failure and other errors in configuration or connectivity for getting all the logs, red/orange/green status lights and other diagnostic and guided repair tips.

- [Mac Mail - Account already exists error when adding gmail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180785/mac-mail-account-already-exists-error-when-adding-gmail)

Comment: connection doctor says:could not connect to imap

Comment: @AlejandraSeeber Double click that item and you can see what changes you can make. If you validate you have it configured, then it's a support call to the IMAP vendor to validate network connectivity and correlate the error message you get and what they see server side.